# Can One Embed A Struct In A Struct To Satisfy An Interface

Tags: interface, struct, go, embedding

I have the following code (also available in the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4f-F618bc7)). Is it possible to instantiate an A struct such that it contains an embedded C, S and an X. The reason I am using interfaces is because, depending on the Build function I call, I'd like to have structs that have different implementations of Bar(). I could have an S1 or an S2, where Bar() is slightly different, but both are S'ers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cer interface {
    Foo()
}

type Ser interface {
    Bar()
}

type Aer interface {
    Cer
    Ser
}

type C struct {
    CField string
}

func (this *C) Foo() {
}

type S struct {
    SField string
}

func (this *S) Bar() {
}

type X struct {
    XField string
}

type A struct {
    Cer
    Ser
    X
}

func main() {
    x := new(X)
    a := Build(x)
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func Build(x *X) A {
    a := new(A)
    a.X = *x
    a.XField = "set x"
    return *a
}
```

Comment: If you want to embed an A in an A, you'll need to use a pointer type at some point (a struct can't have its own value type as a field).

Comment: Sorry. I want to embed a C, S and X. I updated the question. Thanks for the catch. The Build() function embeds an X; I have learned how to do that in Go. But, I'm wondering how to get a C and an S in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: Yes, you can.

But when embedding interfaces, you will have a runtime error incase you try to call the embedded method without having given a value first.

So, the following works fine:

```
a := Build(x)
// Removing the line below will cause a runtime error when calling a.Foo()
a.Cer = &C{"The CField"}
a.Foo()
```

Comment: I built on the play link here: http://play.golang.org/p/Jo0a20gqMZ.  You can see that your A instance satisfies the interface.

Comment: dethtron500 Yes, it does satisfy it. But you cannot call the method a.Foo() before you've given a.Cer a value. In a similar way, this won't work: `s := fmt.Stringer(nil); fmt.Println(s.String())`

Comment: Hmm. I was trying to do so inside Build with a new(C), but that doesn't work. What's the nuance I am missing between the new() and the &C{""} one? See Build() in http://play.golang.org/p/8InbCFaufX

Comment: @alphadogg There is no difference between `new(C)` and `&C{}`. So, in Build(), this should work: `a.Cer = new(C)`

Comment: @alphadogg The compile error in your [playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/8InbCFaufX) is because you cannot access a field of a struct stored in an interface without first doing a type assertion. So your line should look like: `a.Cer.(*C).CField = "set c"`. If all Cer's also should have a CField, then you should created Cer methods like `SetCField()` and such.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't help. I thought I could "plugin" a C1, C2 or C3 "behind" the Cer. But, then other functions would have to know what the Cer actually is to get to the fields.

Comment: @alphadogg Yes, the static type system requires you do know which Cer (or at least a list of possible Cer's in a type switch) in order to access fields.

Comment: @ANisus: Or, define the setters and getters as part of the interface, I guess.